# Unable to play Vimeo video on Safari browser using Windows machine

Tags: video, iframe, safari, fancybox, vimeo

In our website, on a click of a button, a Vimeo video should be played on fancybox.

But on Safari browser (using Windows machine) a black window appears and video is not displayed. Following javascript error also appears:
**Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL [Current page URL] from frame with URL [Vimeo video URL]. Domain, potocols and parts must match.**

If video is played in vimeo website itself using video id, then it works properly. But when it is played in vimeo player, then it doen't work as expected.

Consider the following example:

If video id is 215101646. It works fine with https://vimeo.com/215101646, but it does not work with https://player.vimeo.com/video/215101646

I'm using second link to display video on fancybox. It works fine with all other browsers and even it working fine on Safari while using Mac machine.

I'm using Safari v5.1.4

Comment: Please find information about fancybox in this [http://fancybox.net/](http://fancybox.net/) link

Comment: Apple discontinued development of Safari for Windows several years ago.